# Stripe: do checks before accepting a payment

Tags: javascript, java, stripe-payments, payment

I have stripe already integrated and working but now I'm trying to manage some "corner cases" that can happen in a regular usage and found a case that i'm not sure how to manage.

In my platform all the products i will provide are going to be unique and buyable only once. If 2 people try to buy the same product concurrently, one of them will get it, and the other should get an error when trying to complete the payment.

Currently i have setup webhooks so the backend is able to detect the case but i don't know how to notify stripe to cancel that PaymentIntent at that exact moment, being able to notify also the user.

Is there anything i can do to achieve this? would i be able to cancel the PaymentIntent on that moment so the user can have a custom error message?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like you want to do two things. First, use [separate auth and capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) so that you can capture the funds only when you're sure the sale is happening, and then use the API to [capture](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/capture) or [cancel](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/cancel) the PaymentIntent as appropriate when you see the webhooks.

Comment: i have it separately as i only capture the money until i confirm the availability of the product. The problem is that i don't know how to return an error to the client that didn't get the product in the checkout form instead of notifying him afterwards...

Comment: Due to the asyncronous nature of this, you'd need to perform some sort of polling on your frontend to your backend, checking for a confirmation of "yes, it's available" or not. Essentially you'll show the user "waiting for confirmation..." on the redirect page until your backend confirms availability.

Comment: I guess that's going to be the solution. it would be nice to be able to return a specific error code to stripe on the web-hooks to cancel the transaction at some point, but this can be useful also for other cases. Thanks!